# When/Why do Rust Traits Need to be `use`d/Imported

Tags: module, rust, package, rust-cargo

When/why do Rust traits need to be `use`d/Imported, or why does this question not make sense?

I'm an experienced programmer, but I'm new to Rust.

I'm working my way through [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) -- in [chapter 2](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html) there's the following statment.

> First, we add a `use` line: `use rand::Rng`. The `Rng` trait defines methods that random number generators implement, and **this trait must be in scope for us to use those methods**. Chapter 10 will cover traits in detail.

Emphasis mine.

It's not clear to me why this program

```
use std::io;
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);

    println!("The secret number is: {}", secret_number);

    println!("Please input your guess.");

    let mut guess = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("You guessed: {}", guess);
}
```

needs to `use rand::Rng`.  When we `use/imported` the `std::io` symbol, we got access to an `io` symbol that we could call associated functions on.

```
io::stdin
```

In my naive (and incorrect) view, using `use rand::Rng` would give us an `Rng` symbol.  Instead, we got a `rand` symbol that we could call a `thread_rng` method on.

```
let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);
```

My naive view would be that in order to call `thread_rng`, we'd need to do something like

```
use rand;
// or
use rand::rand
```

What am I, as the programmer, doing when I put `use rand::Rng` in my program, and why is this different from `use std::io`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rand` "symbol" is the name of an external crate, which is in the root namespace irrespective of any `use` statements.  It defines a function `thread_rng()` that is also available (through namespace-qualification with `rand::`) irrespective of your `use` statements.

Therefore, even without your use statements, you can do:

```
let thread_rng = rand::thread_rng();
```

However, `thread_rng` returns a [`rand::rngs::ThreadRng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.3/rand/rngs/struct.ThreadRng.html) struct, upon which you are attempting to call `gen_range`—and it is *this* function that is a trait method, which is not in-scope until the `rand::Rng` trait is brought in with a `use` statement.

It is actually possible to call trait methods even without `use` statements:

```
rand::Rng::gen_range(&mut rand::thread_rng(), 1, 101);
```

...but generally speaking, `use` is much cleaner.

Comment: Is the `gen_range` method of `Rng` trait implemented for `ThreadRng`? I couldn't find any evidence of this in the rand crate.
Even if that is the case, why do we still need to `use` the trait when the method is defined on the struct? Is to to help Rust in namespace qualification?

Comment: I read the documentation and my understanding is that `Rng` trait is automatically implemented for any type that implements the `RngCore` trait. This answers the first part of my question in the comment above, although I'm not sure if my understanding is correct.

Comment: So to use a mod, callers are forced to know which trait the type impl? Even there isn't a conflict? Rust is odd

Comment: Ohh I see. `pub mod trait` could solve this problem.